# Toast in a Thread inside Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, toast

I am developing an application, which would show user the call details(something more which is shown by default). I have tried with a Toast message. But this message dissapears when phone shows the the call accept/reject options, no matter what duration I provide for the Toast message.

Can I use Thread to show the Toast message ? If so, can anyone please provide me the code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Thread.. because Toast is Actually shown by UI thread which is run bu the android OS.. Rather You can make use Of AsyncTAsk.. to know how to use AsyncTAsk [refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)